# How to prepend a new li element into content_tag_for block with jQuery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm trying to write a coffeescript to prepend a new element into a content_tag_for block. And if possible using a partial for code simplicity sake.

```
<ul id="documents">
  <% @documents.each do |document| %>
    <%= content_tag_for :li, document do %>
           <%= document.title %>
           <%= document.position %>
           <%= link_to 'Delete', document, method: :delete, remote: true %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

And my create.js.coffee attempt. But using a partial caused issues because when I run this, the element is added without a

wrapping, breaking sorting and stylizing behavior until after a page reload. I want to append the new record asynchronously using jQuery of course.

```
$('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @document))%>')
  .prependTo('#documents')
  .hide()
  .fadeIn()
$('#new_document')[0].reset()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.
my updated create.js.coffee

```
$('<%= content_tag_for :li, @document do %>
          <%= render @document %>
        <% end %>')
  .prependTo('#documents')
  .hide()
  .fadeIn()
$('#new_document')[0].reset()
```